# MVEL nested property resolution issue

Tags: java, mvel

I have the following class

```
private static class Person{
    private int iq;  
    private Person[] minions;

    public int getIq() {
        return iq;
    }
    public Person[] getMinions() {
        return minions;
    } 
}
```

I'm trying out the following MVEL (1.3.16-java1.6) expression against this code

```
count = 0;
foreach (minion : minions){ 
    if (minions[count].iq > 120) { 
        return true;
    } 
}
return false;
```

However MVEL seems to have problems with the `minions[count].iq` (or even `minions[0].iq`) construct.

Any inputs would be appreciated. The compilers exact grouse is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.mvel.optimizers.impl.asm.ASMAccessorOptimizer can not access a member of class Person with modifiers "public"
```

Comment: I don't know MVEl but since the `Person` class is private `ASMAccessorOptimizer` might actually not see `Person` or might not have the access rights.

Comment: @Thomas. good catch. MVEL had no problems with expressions like "iq<50" etc, even though the class was private. That kinda threw me off. If you can add an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: Added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Person` class is private, thus I assume it would not be visible to `ASMAccessorOptimizer` or if it would, `ASMAccessorOptimizer` would not have the rights to access it.

Declaring  `Person` public should solve that issue.